# Is there any shortcut for this if statement?

Tags: c++

I'm doing my homework and get a problem. Please teach me if there is any shortcut for my "if".

```
if ch=='a'||ch=='o'||ch=='y'||ch=='e'||ch=='u'||ch=='i'||ch=='A'||ch=='O'||ch=='Y'||ch=='E'||ch=='U'||ch=='I') then continue;
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with this code? Do you just want to filter for certain values or do you want to do something with each match?

Comment: Do you really believe that this is C++?

Comment: `if (string s = "aoyeuiAOYEUI"; s.find(ch) != string::npos)`? *C++17*

Comment: There are several ways to write this in fewer keystrokes, but none of them will teach you new and exciting stuff about if-else specifically.

Comment: I'm actually curious as to what the original homework question is... And it seems like the OP did not put much effort into understanding or at least trying to understand what the question is about.

Comment: @Dmitry Kuzminov What do you mean? I think I've just found my mistake in that code

Comment: Do try and give us code that could at least *theoretically* compile. This is missing key syntactical elements. There's nothing wrong with being new to a language, but you must try and adhere to the syntax rules or you're in for a world of hurt and misery.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you interpret `shortcut`: If you just want to write less code, you could have:

```
if(strchr("aoyeuiAOYEUI", ch)) { /* ... */ }
```

But that just hides the work away, actually, there's even more to do (checking for the character in question *and* the terminating null character)...

If you think into opposite direction, you can use a lookup table:

```
static int const Lookup[256] = { ['a'] = 1, ['o'] = 1, /* ... */ };
// values not specified explicitly are set to 0

if(Lookup[ch]) { /* ... */ }
```

That will cost some memory, but with only 256 entries, that won't hurt (if it is a concern, you can safe some if using `char` or `bool` in trade for a bit of speed). It is probably the fastest you can get, though. Similarly a switch/case likely is more efficient as well (often a jump table is created internally, but if it is or not is left to the compiler, there's no guarantee):

```
switch(ch)
{
    case 'a': case 'o': /* ... */
        /* ... */
        break; // in case of continue, as in question, or even return,
               // there's no need for the break...
    default:
        /* what's to be done if NOT matching */
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use `std::toupper()` or `std::tolower()` to reduce the number of possible characters you need to compare in half.

```cpp
char my_toupper(char ch)
{
    return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));
}
```

Then, you can use `std::find()`, `std::string::find()`, or a `switch` statement, to compare the remaining possibilities:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

const char vowels[6] = "AOYEUI";

if (std::find(std::begin(vowels), std::end(vowels), my_toupper(ch)) != std::end(vowels))
    continue;
```

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

const std::string vowels("AOYEUI");

if (vowels.find(my_toupper(ch)) != std::string::npos)
    continue;
```

```cpp
#include <cctype>

switch (my_toupper(ch))
{
    case 'A':
    case 'O':
    case 'Y':
    case 'E':
    case 'U':
    case 'I':
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` or `unordered_set`. It will allow you to know if it is present in one operation, no need to chain conditions.

I converted the characters to lower case, so we don't need as many entries in the set, but you could easily just include both lower and upper case chars in the set.

Here's an example that cycles through an array of possible values and prints the results.

e.g.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::unordered_set<char> s{'a', 'o', 'y', 'u', 'i'};
    char chars[] = {
        'a', 'o', 'y', 'u', 'i', 
        'A', 'O', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 
        'b', 'Z', 's', 'd'
    };

    for(char c: chars)
    {
        if(s.find(tolower(c)) != s.end())
            std::cout << c << " YES\n";
        else
            std::cout << c << " NO\n";
    }
}
```